# Cannot access responsive image sources from Twig

Tags: 8, theming

In Twig I am unable to retrieve the file source for each responsive image style on a ImageItem. How should I be getting this information?

Comment: An alternative would be to be able to get the responsive image id

Answer (score 1):

-You can use a theme hook to wire in the responsive image sources (yourtheme.theme)

-You can set your content / (or custom entity) "manage display" / the image field: set responsive display. So it will send to the dom all of the url's when rendering the item.